# Duda sobre la función readline y generacion de variables

Tags: r

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y actualmente estoy un poco colgado con la función readline. He estado trabajando en un script con la funcion readline que me permitiera ingresar el valor de un nombre de país, que me permitiera registrarlo y luego usar el valor ingresado para que me entregue el valor de la columna de al lado, pero al intentar hacerlo no me reconoce el texto ingresado. Adjunto el codigo:

```
setwd("mi directorio")

covid=read.table("covid.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
muertes=covid$muertes
pais=covid$Entity
casos=covid$casos

#Si ingresamos el nombre del país

{ingrese_pais=readline("Ingrese el nombre del pais:")}
datosmuertes=covid[which(covid==("ingrese_pais")), 2]
print(paste("El numero de muertes es:", datosmuertes))
```

Al escribir el nombre del pais y luego ejecutar las lineas siguientes no me entrega el dato que quiero que me entregue, no se como hacer que el readline se guarde o se acople a lo siguiente

Cualquier solución sería de gran ayuda

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal que veo, es esta línea:

```
datosmuertes=covid[which(covid==("ingrese_pais")), 2]
```

Las comillas no van, ya que estamos hablando de la variable `ingrese_pais` y no de la cadena literal `"ingrese_pais"`. Entiendo que en realidad deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
datosmuertes = muertes[which(pais == ingrese_pais), 2]
```

O bien, puedes trabajar directamente con el `data.frame` sin necesidad de abrir cada columna en nuevos vectores, haciendo esto:

```
datosmuertes = covid$muertes[which(covid$pais == ingrese_pais)]
```

o más simple, sin la necesidad del `which`:

```
datosmuertes = covid$muertes[covid$pais == ingrese_pais]
```

También, ten en cuenta, si usas **Rstudio**, que para que `readline()` funcione adecuadamente, debes salvar tu Script y ejecutarlo luego mediante el botón "source", las otras formas de ejecutar código en Rstudio no son consistentes con la funcionalidad de `readline()`.

Comment: muchas gracias, ha sido de gran ayuda, aunque al utilizar la opcion sin el which, al crear la variable la crea como integer(empty). De todas formas entendí la logica y me sirvio mucho.